# Can I unplug my Mac mini from power once it's in hibernate mode?

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-mini, power

Suppose I want to work on my Mac mini here, reach a certain point in my work, then put it in hibernate mode and unplug the power.

From what I understand the hibernate mode will save the status of the Mac into the disk, and will unpower all devices. So, from what I understand, I can now unplug the Mac mini and no damage will occur.

In principle I can take my Mac mini into my messenger bag, drive 2 hours to home, and once at home attach it to a power plug with its cord and power it back on. At that stage the Mac will take some time to restore from disk, but I will have got the same status of my Mac as when I switched it off.

Please note this is not the same as "reopen current windows", because certain programs have a more complex status than just having an open window and its position. For one example (and there are several) you can think to Terminal.app. If you have multiple tabs open each history of commands is preserved separately until you quit the Terminal.app, once you quit only one tab history is saved to file and persist to your next reboot (btw, I am aware there "fixes" to this behaviour, but they do not apply to my actual case, I just need to carry an example).

Do you see any flaws in my story? Is it really possible to unplug the Mac mini once it has gone into hibernate mode?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the "reopen current windows" option on shutdown not work for some reason?

Comment: While I've not personally tried it and probably wouldn't, I'd power it down properly before disconnecting it from power, nonetheless when the `/var/vm/sleepimage` file is restored to RAM the OS is probably going to have issues with a whole different set of peripherals being attached and not properly initialized as they would have from a clean boot or plugged in while the OS was actually running when plugged in and not suspended to an image file.  Anyway, let us know how it goes.

Comment: Reopen windows will work if you have an SSD.  Those are lightning fast already.

Comment: @agentroadkill "reopen current windows"  unfortunately is not a solution, because I need to restore also the status of certain applications, which cannot be easily saved to file like a word processor document (terminal.app, wolfram mathematica (for speed reasons), etc)

Comment: @user3439894 I do not have a Mac mini yet, I was asking because I am considering buying one. So I would appreciate if somebody has tried or does this regularly. If you commute between two locations where you have external screen and keyboard+mouse to attach to your mac book I think a Mac mini can have some advantages over the laptop.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't unplug your Mac unless it's shut off; however you *can* do it using hibernate mode. The closest to hibernate is in this answer, [How can I manually put a Macbook Pro to hibernate without going to sleep mode first?](https://superuser.com/a/630985), it outlines how to enable hibernate on your Mac, which it actually copies the memory to the disk, and if you loose power, it restores the memory. It's made for MacBooks, but will work fine for any Mac.

The Reopen Windows feature should work, but I don't like using at, as it can significantly slow down startup (and login) speed.

Comment: Would there be a sign of 'hibernated', indicating I can unplug a (desktop) Mac safely? Either hibernatemode 3 or 25.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested using the settings from Peter Rigby's answer here and they work fine:

https://superuser.com/questions/139354/how-can-i-manually-put-a-macbook-pro-to-hibernate-without-going-to-sleep-mode-fi/630985#630985

In a console switching the hibernation mode to 25 will make make a Mac Mini hibernate instead of sleep:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
```

To revert it back to the default  (which powers the ram and writes image to disk)

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3
```

To list your current settings

```
pmset -g
```

If you want to sleep/hibernate your machine from the command line do

```
pmset sleepnow
```

Or select sleep from Menu - your mac will hibernate to disk - I have a Macmini8,1 with the 6-Core Intel Core i5 and 64 GB of Memory, it takes about 30-120 seconds until the light turns off and I can unplug and start again elsewhere.